# Wireless networking - Strange WiFi Issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

My devices (computer, phone etc.) are connected to a WiFi extender provided by my landlord, I don't have physical access to the router.

Just in the last few days a strange problem has developed where all of my devices will connect to the WiFi but there will be no Internet connection at all. If I then connect to another network (directly to the router) which has a very weak signal (the reason for the extender) and then switch back to the extender it suddenly works fine. However this only lasts till when the devices are put to sleep or shutdown/restarted when the problem starts up again.

Below I'll list all of the networks in the house that are connected to the router:

1. Apt. A (The one I switch to)
2. Apt. A_EXT (My desired network)
3. Apt. B
4. Landlord WiFi
5. Landlord WiFi_EXT

Comment: It sounds like the repeater is not handing out the correct DNS server information. As a test; connect to the `Apt.A-EXT` and see if you can ping google's IP without going to google.com.

`ping 74.125.224.72`

Comment: What's your actual, specific question?  Also, your landlord has taken responsibility as your ISP, and you are willingly patronizing him as such. It's up to him to fix it, especially since you don't have any control given to you.

Comment: @Atari911 I get "this webpage is not available" when I turn it on, if I switch and switch back it connects fine. 

I'd love to ask him but he's been pretty reluctant to help when I've mentioned it to him before.

Comment: Did you test the DNS resolution by pinging the IP I listed above? This will at least allow you to get an idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the extender or router is not renewing the IP address or dns information when the devices reconnect to the network. Disconnecting and reconnecting is the only viable solution in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I seems the DHCP server connected to your 1st ESSID is not working and that both the essids work in the same IP range. So when you connect to second essid you get the ip address which you are able to use when you connect back to first.